# Live preview on Latexian

Tags: latexian, live-preview

noob here, when translating a technical manual from english to spanish live preview stopped showing almost last third of the manual. I have the same preview file for the appendix chapter (the one that I'm current on) as any of the other chapters before, only clue that I have is an error message "File ended while scanning use of \syntaxDescription"

Any help will be much appreciated !!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! From the description it seems that you are missing a closing brace.